# Git shortcut to pull with clone if no local there yet?

Tags: git, jenkins

Is there a one-command way to get an up-to-date mirror of a remote repo? 
That is

- if local repo not there yet: clone
- if it's there: pull

I know I could script this around (e.g `if [ -d repo ]; then (cd repo && git pull); else git clone $repourl;fi`
) , but I need the simplest possible cross-platform way (actually used for Jenkins-CI, which I know does this by default, however I need 2 repos for which support is limited).

Git has similar shortcuts for other things (eg. checkout -b, and pull itself), so I'm wondering if I missed something. Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought of writing a new git alias for this purpose?

Comment: Where should it clone the repository from?

Comment: Why do you need access to the 2nd repository? Is it possible to remodel this so that your project depends on locally deployed artifacts from the 2nd project?

Comment: @Steinar  Apart from the main source repo, I have a little one with a bunch of scripts I'd like to use for just of the build jobs. I know I could add this as a submodule, but that would be too intrusive at this stage. I've tried the Multi-SCM plugin, but that doesn't play with ParametrizedTrigger/Pass gitcommit option.

Comment: Could you use git submodules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`git pull`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) knows from where to pull from because the local repo has a remote registered in its local config. It operates from a working tree.

But [`git clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) doesn't, it must have an explicit remote URL passed in parameter in order to clone. It operates outside the working tree.

The main reason for such a shortcut to *not* exist is that:

- you `git clone` rarely for a given repo: it is a one-time command in the life of the repo.
  Plus, it might need *an additional* command to be complete: if you have submodules, for instance, you would need to add a `git submodule update --init`.
- you `git pull` often within a given repo. `git pull` is in itself a shortcut (for `git fetch` + `git merge`). Even `git pull --rebase` is another shortcut for `git fetch` + `git rebase`.

Considering the number of times you are to use `git clone`, such a shortcut is not a high priority.

So a script remains the surest way to define what you need.

Comment: Ok, but I thought I'd pass the "url" to such a command.. E.g. git-clone-or-pull $URL $branch. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @inger I agree: you would have to pass that as a parameter to the script/alias you would define.

Comment: BTW, the reason I'm hesitant to accept this answer, is I find it slightly misleading.. I mean: git 'could' provide this shortcut but it does not - so client tools(scripts,CI,etc) have to do this themselves.. No big deal BUT it doesn't have much to do with some ad-hoc limitation of clone and pull. Just as 'checkout -b' creates the branch as well as checkout (conversely git-gui offers checkout when creating the branch), it would be a nice -tiny- addition in git to do these in 1 go (unless it's against some principle). So to me, the answer sounds like: no shortcut yet, you need to script around.

Comment: @inger my point is not that git could not, it is that git *cannot*: `git clone` doesn't run with an existing working tree/git repo: it requires an empty or non-existent directory. As opposed to `git pull` (or the combo `git checkout -b`), which are running within a working tree. So due to the difference in the running environment between a `git clone` (no working tree) and a `git pull` (working tree), it makes sense there is no shortcut for that particular combination of commands.

Comment: thanks for clarifying, but, my point wasn't "could vs. can" either,just that I would not 'blame' it to whatever clone does now(as the answer seems to be suggesting) ..Anyway, it's already just a shortcut to sg like init+remote+fetch+checkout, and only the first step is affected by the existence of the local dir, after that it just operates within that. So, IMHO this does not explain the lack of a pull shortcut (not saying there are no other reasons, probably it's too much of a "nice to have")..IOW,to me this implication is slighly misleading.

Comment: This answer confused me. For repositories that you're cloning, you might _never_ have used `git init`. What does `git init` have to do with the question?

Comment: @BrentBradburn Re-reading this answer 10 years later (to the day!), I agree. I have edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 97):

There is not, given that the commands which operate on existing repos all assume that they're being run inside a given repo.

That said, if you're running in a shell, you could simply make use of the shell built-ins. For instance, here's bash:

```
if cd repo; then git pull; else git clone https://server/repo repo; fi
```

This checks to see if `repo` is a valid directory, and if so, does a `pull` within it; otherwise it does a `clone` to create the directory.

Comment: A more precise answer than mine regarding the script part: +1

Comment: Thanks, so the suspect was right, need a script (ie. dependency external to git). However I'm not sure about the reasoning "given that the commands which operate on existing repos all assume that they're being run inside a given repo": git-clone does not assume that, for example.. It's easy to imagine a switch'--pull-if-there' - of course that's the first thing I checked, not to avail.

Comment: @VonC, except the question wasn't really about the script part.. By the way, it seems incorrect, should be --git-dir=repo/.git

Comment: @inger yes, it should be `repo/.git` indeed

Comment: @inger I would also add a `--work-tree=repo` in order to be sure to be able to run a `git pull` from anywhere.

Comment: Hmm good point.. Just one more refinement, it seems I need --work-tree=$PWD/repo -ie to use absolute path, relative does not seem to be working (even though the man page says so). Git 1.7.10.4

Comment: Maybe just easier to (cd repo && git pull) after all:)

Comment: @inger yes, in that case, a `cd` is easier for setting both the working tree and the git repo path.

Comment: Yeah, updated it to just use `cd`. Also, @inger - `git clone` doesn't operate on existing repos.

Comment: Thanks - but are you sure about this "if [ cd repo ];"... Re:   'git clone doesn't operate on existing repos' - I know, that's why I asked if there was another option.

Comment: @Amber Shouldn't that be, if cd repo; -- without the brackets?

Comment: Great stuff, helped me with my script. Please note that the result of the script is inconsistent - you're either in the repo directory if it existed or outside of it if not. To change that, add "&& cd repo" right after the git clone command.

Comment: @falconizer - see my solution using `pushd` instead of `cd`

Comment: I think this is the cleanest shell-based solution. I suggest using `if cd 2>/dev/null`... to avoid an irrelevant error message when the folder doesn't exist. There's also the issue of inconsistency because the resulting working directory depends on which path is taken. In Bash scripts, I normally wrap operations with `cd` in parentheses so that they operate in a [subshell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/138463/6764), preserving state. When launching this from a separate tool/script the subshell is implicit. _ToSelf: I'm on the fence about if it would be smart to check for the `.git` folder._

Answer (score 74):

The cleanest one-liner might be

```
git -C repo pull || git clone https://server/repo repo
```

Comment: on Git version < 1.8.5 (Q4 2013), it's `Unknown option: -C`

Comment: This one is tempting, but has the flaw of displaying "fatal: cannot change to '...': no such file or directory" before cloning.

Answer (score 3):

`git -C repo pull` will only work on [git 1.8.5](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5fd09df3937f54c5cfda4f1087f5d99433cce527/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.5.txt#L115-L116) or above. To achieve this on **earlier versions**, try:

```
remote_repo=https://server/repo
local_repo=repo

if [ -d $local_repo/.git ]; then pushd $local_repo; git pull; popd; else git clone $remote_repo; fi
```

Comment: What is the -C option? I'm struggling to find  documentation on it.

Comment: @TwainJ `git --help` shows -C <path>. It's the path where the command will run. In this scenario, it helps to avoid writing `cd repo && git pull && cd ..`

Answer (score 3):

If upgrading git is not an option, and you don't want to pass an argument for a repo, a scripting approach could be:

```
#!/bin/bash

function clone_pull {
  DIRECTORY=$(basename "$1" .git)
  if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
    cd "$DIRECTORY"
    git pull
    cd ../
  else
    git clone "$1"
  fi
}

clone_pull https://github.com/<namespace>/<repo>
# or
clone_pull git@github.com:<namespace>/<repo>.git
```

Answer (score 2):

Idempotent git-clone has sensible use-cases (especially when scripted).

There is an off-the-shelf implementation here (requires [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/)): [git-clone-idempotent](https://github.com/mafintosh/git-clone-idempotent)

```
$ nvm install node ## if you have nvm but not node/npm
$ npm install -g git-clone-idempotent

$ git-clone-idempotent repo [folder]
```

---

This approach may be more OS-portable than solutions based on shell scripting.

Comment: Interesting alternative. Upvoted.

Comment: Unfortunately, this utility fails if you've checked out a revision without tracking a remote branch (the `pull` fails): "Please specify which branch you want to merge with."

Comment: There's probably room for improvement, but here's what I've done most recently: `function my-git-clone-idempotent { repo=$1; folder=$(basename $repo .git); git 2>/dev/null clone $repo || git 2>/dev/null -C $folder pull || git -C $folder fetch; }`

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned Jenkins, it is possible to clone or pull using the [Jenkins SCM API](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/). The `checkout` method does exactly what you want.

You can run it from a groovy script like so:

```
dir (targetFolder) {
  checkout(scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: 'master']], ...])
}
```

Note that it does not check out the specified branch in the git sense, but rather leaves the workspace on a detached head at the corresponding commit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another 1-liner. In contrast to other solutions here, this code does not output an error in the terminal:

```sh
(test -d my-repo && git -C my-repo pull --rebase) || \
  git clone https://github.com/my-repo my-repo
```

Here is a variation where the repo and source URL are variables, so you don't need to repeat the repo-folder three times:

```sh
DIR=my-repo && ORIGIN=https://github.com/my-repo/ && \
  (test -d $DIR && git -C $DIR pull --rebase) || git clone $ORIGIN $DIR
```