# # how to solvemy jenkins output

Tags: jenkins-plugins

#output i get when i run same code.
Started by user Onyinye Ezike
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/building
[building] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins10267950197247538821.sh

- git clone https://github.com/CeeyIT-Solutions/JavaCalculator-1.git
  fatal: destination path 'JavaCalculator-1' already exists and is not an empty directory.
  Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
  Finished: FAILURE

have install all the all tools i need. the process was suppose to build but it failed kept saying it already existed

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your workspace folder already exists and you are trying to clone the git repo into it again. There are two options for you here. One is to use [cleanWS](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ws-cleanup/) to remove the directory after the build has finished so the next time the build runs the workspace is going to be empty. The other option is to use the [GitSCM plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/) and checkout the code with that so that it handles cases where the repo is already present in the local machine.

One more option could be to first check if the repo already exists, and if yes, pull. If not, clone. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15602111/3730626) shows how that is done.